# If $G(x)=P[X\geq x]$ then $X\geq c$ is equivalent to $G(X)\leq G(c)$ $P$-almost surely

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality

> Suppose $[\Omega,\mathcal{F},P]$ denotes a probability triplet and $X:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ is a real-valued random variable. Define
>   $$
> G(x)=P[X\geq x].
> $$
>   **Claim**: for any constant $c$, the event $X\geq c$  is equivalent to $G(X)\leq G(c)$ possibly except for a set of measure $0$. Can you please help me understand this?

**Edit**: I think I have one direction. Let
$$
A=\{w\in\Omega:X(w)\geq c\},\quad B=\{w:G(X(w))\leq G(c)\}.
$$
Fix $\bar{w}\in A$. I claim that $\bar{w}\in B$. Indeed, $\bar{w}\in A$ implies $X(\bar{w})\geq c$ so that $\{X\geq X(\bar{w})\}\subset\{X\geq c\}$. This gives
$$
P[X\geq X(\bar{w})]\leq P[X\geq c]\iff G(X(\bar{w}))\leq G(c)\iff\bar{w}\in B.
$$

Comment: For the other direction, you assume that $G(X(\overline{w})) \leq G(c)$ _and_ that $X(\overline{w})<c$.  Then show this means the value of $X(\overline{w})$ must be interior to a flat region of the distribution function. You also need to show that the probability of being in such a place is zero.

Comment: @Michael: with your hint, $X(\bar{w})<c$ implies $G(X(\bar{w}))\geq G(c)$ so that $P[X(\bar{w})\leq X<c]=0$. But then I'm stuck. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: What's the question??

Comment: $G$ is a monotonously decreasing function. That is, for any reals $a,b$: $$a\le b$$ is equivalent to $$G(a)\ge G(b).$$What difference does it make if one of the reals at stake is selected randomly?

Comment: @Zoli $G$ is not necessarily strictly decreasing though.

Comment: @user2345215 I'm trying to understand why $X\geq c\iff G(X)\leq G(c)$ $P$-almost surely.

Comment: We have "less or equal" and the probability of the constant segments is $0$. However, I don't know why the constant segments count...

Comment: @Zoli: that's where my confusion is. Can you write out a full answer for the direction that makes me stuck? I will really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the event $\mathcal{H}$ according to my hint above (where $\mathcal{H}$ stands for "hint"): 
$$ \mathcal{H} =  \{\omega'\in\Omega: G(X(\omega') ) \leq G(c)\}\cap \{\omega'\in\Omega : X(\omega')< c\} $$

We want to show that $Pr[\mathcal{H}]=0$. 
Your reply to my hint shows you already got most of the way:  I think you agree that:

$$ \mathcal{H} \subseteq \{\omega'\in\Omega: X(\omega') < c\}\cap \{\omega'\in\Omega : G(X(\omega'))=G(c)\} $$

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ such that there is a $y\in\mathbb{R}$ for which $x<y$ and $G(x)=G(y)$ (where $\mathcal{F}$ stands for "flat").  Thus:

$$\mathcal{H}  \subseteq \{\omega'\in\Omega : X(\omega') \in \mathcal{F}\} $$

and so:

\begin{align} 
Pr[\mathcal{H}] &\leq Pr[\{\omega'\in\Omega : X(\omega') \in \mathcal{F}\}] \\
&\equiv Pr[X \in \mathcal{F}] 
\end{align}

So it suffices to prove that $Pr[X \in \mathcal{F}] =0$.

---

Proving $Pr[X \in \mathcal{F}]=0$. Since the function $G(x)$ is non-increasing, the set $\mathcal{F}$ is either empty, or consists of a finite or countably infinite number of disjoint intervals $\{I_i\}$.  You can show that $Pr[X \in I_i] =0$ for all $i$, and so $Pr[X \in \mathcal{F}]=\sum_iPr[X \in I_i] = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much professor for your comments and answer!

Comment: You are welcome.  I just edited the last two sentences above to change "disjoint open intervals $\{I_i\}$" to "disjoint intervals $\{I_i\}$," since such an interval could be $[1, \infty)$.  For example, if $X$ is uniform over $[0,1]$ then $\mathcal{F}=(-\infty,0) \cup [1,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

$G(x)=1-P(X<x)\implies G(c)=1-P(X<c)$

Now, $X\geq c \implies X|X\geq c := X'=c+\epsilon, \epsilon\geq 0$ where $\epsilon$ is a random variable on the same sample space as $X$

The definition of $X'$ implies:

$G(X')=G(c+\epsilon)=1-[P(X<c)+P(X\in[c,c+\epsilon))]=G(c)-P(X\in[c,c+\epsilon))$

Now, $P(X\in[c,c+\epsilon))$ is a *random variable*, since $\epsilon$ is a random variable.

By the definition of probability $P(X\in[c,c+\epsilon))\geq0 \implies G(X')=G(c+\epsilon)\leq G(c),\; a.s.$

**The other direction**

Assume we have some event $A\in \sigma(X):P[a\in A:G(X(a))> G(c)]=0$ (i.e., $A$ is the event that $G(X)\leq G(c), a.s.)$ and let $Y \sim P_X$, then we get:

$P[a\in A: G(X(a))> G(c)]=P[a\in A:P(Y<X(a))<P(Y<c)]=0 \implies A=\{X\geq c,\;a.s.\}$

$\square$

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong but isn't this another argument for the direction I have already solved in the OP? Could you please help me with the reverse direction? Zoli kindly gave an answer below but that answer was too vague for me.

Comment: @yurnero ah, sorry. Yes, it starts from $X\geq c$ and goes from there. Need to start the other way around too. Ill add that when I get time. Is the above at the right level?

Comment: i'm not familiar with the notation $X|X\geq c:=X'$ but I could generally follow your argument. Thanks. :)

Comment: @yurnero it means I'm defining the conditional random variable, where X is greater than or equal to c, as $X'$...just to save space.

Comment: @yurnero I've added my attempt at the reverse direction.

Comment: Hey I just saw it. Please give me time to digest.

Comment: The notation $Pr[Y<X]$ is kind of confusing to me since it looks like an event involving two random variables, it is not clear what part you are letting be a function of $\overline{w}$.  Does that $X$ perp $Y$ thingy mean $X$ and $Y$ are independent?  I don't think we want to define $X$ and $Y$ like that.  I like the @yurnero notation better.  Your answer might be correct, but I cannot follow it.  Wouldn't you at some point need to note that the sum of all (at most countably infinite) interiors of the flat intervals of $G$ have zero probability?

Comment: For example, if $X$ is uniform over $[0,1]$ then $G(x) = 1-x$ for $x \in [0,1]$ and $G(X) = 1-X$.  But if $X$ and $Y$ are iid then $1-Pr[Y<X]=1/2$, which is different from $G(X)=1-X$. So when you write $Pr[Y<X]$ I think you really mean $Pr[\omega \in \Omega:Y(\omega)<X(\omega')]$, which is a function of $\omega'$.

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 +1 thank you for your time.

Comment: @Michael you're right....my notation is confusing...as an applied math guy, I sometimes omit the sample space notation (its in my head...which doesn't help anyone else ;-) I've clarified what I was trying to say. Hope that helps.

Comment: @yurnero I've clarified my proof, maybe it will provide some additional insight into Michael's nice answer.

Answer (score 0):

Since $G$ is decreasing $G(a)\le G(b)$ is equivalent to $b\le a$ except for the constant segments of $G$.

$a$ and $b$ can be any reals or any real valued functions of any variables, that is even random variables can be plugged in.

If we plug in a random variable (for, say $a$) whose cdf happens to be  $G$ then the   equivalence will hold a.s.   because                                                                     $X$ falls in a constant segment of $G$  with probability $0$.

Comment: @yurnero: I'did answer.

Comment: I appreciate your time but it's a still too vague for me at the moment.